# "ERROR: query has no destination for result data"

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions, set-returning-functions

I am trying to create a function like this:

I tried changing the return type to int or text etc. to see if the code works outside of that, but it doesn't. I am a beginner in PostgreSQL so please don't be harsh if I missed something obvious.

```
create or replace function date_select(i INT) returns void as
$$ 
    begin
        select * from dwh_stg.stg_dce_gift where gift_id = i;
    end
$$ language plpgsql

select date_select(16940)
```

---

**SQL Error [42601]:**

```
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Where: PL/pgSQL function date_select(integer) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Comment: What are you trying to implement?  A function that returns void . . . is unusual in this situation.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return something, you need to define the function to return something (not `void`)

Apparently you want to return multiple rows from the table `stg_dec_gift`, for that you need to define the function as `returns setof dwh_stg.stg_dce_gift`. For a simple function encapsulating a query there is not need to use PL/pgSQL a plain SQL function will do just fine:

```
create or replace function date_select(i INT) 
  returns setof dwh_stg.stg_dce_gift --<<  here
as
$$ 
  select * 
  from dwh_stg.stg_dce_gift 
  where gift_id = i;
$$ 
stable
language sql;
```

Then use it in the `FROM` part:

```
select *
from date_select(16940);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/WYDCE44062

Comment: I tried this code and receive the following error:

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function date_select(integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15

Comment: @bilgecany: there was a typo in my code which prevented the function from being created.